# How to create a content element in typoscript?

Tags: typo3, typoscript

Is there a possible way to create a content element just using typoscript?

I need something like this:

```
ce = CONTENTELEMENT
ce {
    type = textmedia
    header = Hello World
    bodytext = Lorem ipsum
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to create your content element in a storage folder in the backend and then retrieve it with :

```
lib.ce = RECORDS
lib.ce {
    source = theIDOfTheContentElement
    tables = tt_content
}
```

Then you can call your lib in a fluid template with :

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.ce"/>
```

Comment: Thats right, but the content element has to exists und you need to know the id. I played around using FLUIDTEMPLATE but there is no possibility so set the data attributes.